# Como criar uma seleção em um grid no flutter

Tags: flutter, matriz, dart

preciso construir um caça palavras, mas estou com um problema na busca diagonal

Eu consigo esse resultado

[image: Texto],

mas, preciso de uma seleção como a apresentada abaixo

[image: Texto],

Alguém sabe como posso atingir esse resultado, agradeço desde já?

Comment: Adicione um pouco de código em sua pergunta... Para nos mostrar como chegou até esse resultado, quais _Widgets_ está usando e tals

Comment: Mateus obrigado pela resposta, a construção basicamente é um grid de letras, sem preenchimento e usando o gesture detector, onPanStart, onPanUpdate e onPanEnd, quando uma palavra é identificada é inserido preenchimento nos containers, horizontalmente e verticalmente tem um bom resultado, mas na diagonal não funciona.

Normalmente eu insiro código detalhado nas minhas questões, mas nesse caso acredito que pouco agregaria e desfocaria da questao principal, afinal ainda estou buscando entender como fazer uma seleção conforme a imagem2.

Comment: De qualquer maneira, mais tarde irei adicionar um código já que pode facilitar a me ajudar.